# Get Facebook like count using the API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the number of Facebook likes using the API for the page of the organization I work for - https://www.facebook.com/giftoflife. (The number is about 150k.)

`https://graph.facebook.com/110653755631234/insights/page_fans` simply returns no data (I'm using the correct access token).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I need to use the insights API specifically, as I need to get the likes within a specific date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the number of likes for a Page is actually a lot easier, you don´t need the insights for that, and only an App Access Token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/giftoflife
```

You only need a User or Page Token for that if the Page is restricted (age/country).

If you want to get access to Insights, make sure you got a Page Access Token with the `read_insights` permission. You can debug your Access Token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know - but I need the insights as I want to get the likes for a particular time range.

Comment: in that case i am 99% sure you are not using the correct access token with the correct permissions. i will edit my answer.

Comment: i'm using app_id|app_secret as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens - doesn't that include all permissions?

Comment: well...that is only an app token, completely wrong for getting page insights. see my answer, you need a page token.

Comment: This worked, thanks, so I marked it as answer. However I need a permanent token, as I am getting the information from our server (to display a chart). Is this possible?

Comment: extended page tokens are valid forever: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/